# Need to use COLLATION in a SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: t-sql, collation

I am trying to apply collation on a SELECT DISTINCT statement. anyone now how to do this?

One would think that the DISTINCT would detect upper and lower case as different, i.e..   'Yes' and 'YES'.

But DISTINCT does not appear to be case sensitive. So I believe I need to add COLLATE...

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS Shrt_Text AS  Sht_text
FROM  tblMatStrings
```

Any idea on how to distinguish upper and lower in a SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Well, the answers below are perfectly correct : just a detail, the result of `distinct` depends on your `db collation` (or column collation if you manage that at column level) , which is probably `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, or `Latin1_General_CI_AI`

Comment: @Raphael doesn't the collation in the query completely override any applied column or database collation collation?

Comment: Sure. It's just that you wrote `DISTINCT does not appear to be case sensitive`, and I thought you meant `DISTINCT is never Case sensitive`. I may have misunderstood what you where meaning ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've just got your syntax a bit backwards

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Shrt_Text COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS As Shrt_text
FROM   tblMatStrings
```